# Displaying a Table of strings in a window

Tags: c, gtk, text-files, gtk3

I am trying to Display a Table just like this one in a scrolled window which i wrote a code that prints it into a file :

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYrOT.png)

I tried to do the same thing but instead write it in a textview widget , but the characters are not treated the same as in .txt file for instance "AAAAA" and "jjjjj" are both composed of 5 characters , in the .txt file they line up but in the textview the "AAAAA" takes more space which makes the whole table asymmetrical , is there a way to fix it ?

Or maybe there's a better way of implementing it , when i searched for an answer i came upon the treeview widget but i really didn't find examples or clear documentation to follow ,i'd really appreciate an example of how to use it.

And thanks <3.

Comment: Select a fixed space font such as courier.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1TextView.html#a5f12b7435219a14097b6509d0db5361f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to just use the function `gtk_text_view_set_monospace ()` on the text view; this will select the user's default monospace font and is very portable:

```
GtkWidget *text_view = gtk_text_view_new ();

gtk_text_view_set_monospace (text_view, TRUE);

[...]
```